# How do I get Pycharm to show qiskit visualization?

Tags: pycharm, qiskit

I am trying to do the qiskit tutorials in pycharmCE. I can get all the numbers but I am unable to get the graphs to show. Instead of a graph, it prints "Figure(700x700) Here is the code:

```
    from qiskit import *
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
#qunatum circit in bell state
bell = QuantumCircuit(2 ,2)
bell.h(0)
bell.cx(0, 1)

meas =  QuantumCircuit(2, 2)
meas.measure([0,1], [0,1])

#execute Qc
backend = BasicAer.get_backend('qasm_simulator') #the divice to run
circ = bell.compose(meas)
result = backend.run(transpile(circ, backend), shots=1000).result()
counts = result.get_counts(circ)
print(counts)

plot_histogram(counts)
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it works if I import matplotlib.pyplot (`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`). Then you can add `plt.show()` as the last line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what worked for me on Pycharm (to draw the circuit),

```
qc.x(1)
qc.h(range(3))
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure(range(3), range(3))
qc.draw(output='mpl')
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

I had to add both `plt.draw()` and `plt.show()` at end of my code block.